# What is the domain of $\left(\frac{x^2-3}{x^2+4}\right)^{2x^3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I thought the domain of the function
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{x^2-3}{x^2+4}\right)^{2x^3}$$
is $[\sqrt{3},\infty)$, by using the formula
$$x^y = \exp\bigl(y\ln(x)\bigr).$$
But then why I can compute
$$
f(1) = \frac{4}{25} \text{ or } f(0) = 1?
$$
Is this valid? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: This denominator does not limit the domain of the function, but since the exponent can be negative, the numerator is capable of limiting what values the function can accept...

Comment: $a^{2b} = (a^2)^b$ when $a,b\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: @TedShifrin What if $b=1/4$?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Indeed, I spoke way too hastily.

Comment: And yet a homework problem, so .....

Comment: @Aruralreader: IMHO, the OP showed significant effort in-question towards solving the problem, and has readily engaged in trying to understand responses...

Comment: @abiessu Thanks for that. Yes, I am trying to understand the definition of $x^y=\exp(y \ln(x))$ and how this can be used to determine the domain of the provided example. At the beginning I found the interval $(\sqrt{3}, \infty)$, but then I noticed that I could actually compute other values, e.g., at $x=0, x=1$, and $x=\sqrt{3}$. So I was very confused. By the way, the definition I used is from this textbook (page 189):  https://www.jirka.org/ra/realanal.pdf

Comment: You can not get the entire domain by looking at $x^y=\exp(y \ln{x})$ because when you manipulate the mapping rule you change the domain. For example $f(x)=\frac{x^2-x}{x}$ has domain $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ but $g(x)=x-1$ has domain $\mathbb R$, even though $f=g$ everywhere except at $x=0$.

Comment: @RandyMarsh Oh! So, essentially, first we can analyze the function as it is to determine part of the domain, and then we can also use the definition of $x^y$ to determine the other part of the domain. Is that correct? My teachers, most of the time, focus on the definition of $x^y$, but they never mention these little details.

Comment: You should get the full domain from the original mapping rule only. You can apply $x^y = \exp(y\ln x)$ only for those $x$ for which $\ln$ makes sense. This is why you don't get, for example, $0$ as part of the domain, because the rule $x^y = \exp(y\ln x)$ isn't valid when $x\leq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the exponent in this function had a fixed sign, there would be only one portion of this specific function that would determine the domain of it, which would be the denominator.  But this denominator being $x^2+4$ is always positive for $x\in \Bbb R$ so that part is fine.

But this function has an exponent that can be negative, i.e., $2x^3\in(-\infty,\infty)$.  So then we have to check the inverted fraction's denominator for invalid inputs, and we find that $x=-\sqrt 3$ is not part of this function's domain.

Edit for negative to exponents: since the numerator can also be negative with a possible non-rational exponent, these values should be excluded...

Edit: the effective domain of this function is $(-\infty,-\sqrt 3)\cup[\sqrt 3,\infty)\cup\{a\in(-\sqrt 3,\sqrt 3):(-1)^{2a^3}\in\Bbb R\}.$

Comment: So $f(-1)=25/4$ is undefined? Why I can compute it?

Comment: $f(-1)$ is not undefined, since $(-1)^2-3\neq 0.$ But $f(-\sqrt 3)$ is undefined, since the numerator is $0$.

Comment: @DanielMuñoz: please show the calculations leading to the negative number which is the subject of the square root in $x\in\{-1,1\}$...

Comment: @abiessu I got confuse

Comment: @abiessu I am trying to make sense of your last line in your answer. Are you removing  first some terms in the interval and then then the full interval?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the domain is all of the reals less most of the interval around zero.  But there are some values $a$ around zero which should remain, and that includes any where $(-1)^{2a^3}\in\Bbb R$, for example $-1,0,1,\sqrt[3]{2}$ etc.

Comment: @learningmaths I guess it would make more sense to rewrite it so that there isn't a double negative...

Comment: Oh, I see. I totally understand how you got the two intervals. But how did you come up with the expression $(-1)^{2a^3}\in \mathbb R$?

Comment: @learningmaths: inside the interval $x\in(-\sqrt 3,\sqrt 3)$ all the values of $x^2-3$ are negative.  A negative number to a rational power having an even denominator, e.g., $\frac 12,$ is not on the real line, and so the associated $x$ cannot be in the function's domain.  So I am working with $(-1)(3-x^2)$ within the problematic interval, and the exponent from the function, and taking the direct route of saying "$a$ for which $(-1)^{2a^3}$ is a real number."  If I try to enumerate which $a$ satisfy this condition, I may miss some or get some extras.

Comment: Oh! It makes total sense now. Thanks so much! I sincerily appreciate your help with this.

Comment: @abiessu I just kept digging about this kind of problem, and I found this paper that is related to my question: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2691469 This is super interesting! :)

Answer (score 1):

If $x=\sqrt 3$ then we are raising 0 to a positive power, which is legitimate. if $x< \sqrt 3$ we have a negative number that can be rased to a power that is  an integer over an odd integer.   The domain is $$[\sqrt3,\infty) \cup((-\infty,\sqrt3)\cap\{x\vert 2x^3=\frac{a}{b},a \in \mathbb Z, b=\text{odd integer}\})$$

Comment: So $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are undefined, even though I can compute them? I am confused. :(

Comment: @learningmaths $f(0)=1$

Comment: @learningmaths Please see my revised post.

Comment: Your condition should be $|x|\lt \sqrt{3}$, rather that "$x\lt \sqrt{3}$".

Comment: The intersection in your domain is incorrect (I got mine wrong initially also...), You should have $(-\infty,-\sqrt 3)\cup[\sqrt 3,\infty)\cup$ (add values in skipped interval which also work)...

Comment: Interestingly, wolfram alpha gets it wrong when prompted with "domain of f(x)= balbla", it only gives $(-\infty,-\sqrt 3)\cup[\sqrt 3,\infty)$, ignoring anything between $-\sqrt 3$ and $\sqrt 3$ .

Comment: @GáborBuella Yes, I tried Wolfram alpha. I also tried GeoGebra and it plots only on $(\sqrt{3}, \infty)$.